# HTML5 web audio getting stuck (buffering issue?)

Tags: audio, buffer, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am working on a (weekly radio show) audio website and I keep getting the same problem, the audio files that are up to 1hr long keep getting stuck.

I have tested several different players, both the flash player Wimpy Player, and HTML5 players such as Audio5js, jPlayer, and pickle player.

AND I have tested to sample the sound in different bit rates, 8,24,64,128 but the sound files keeps getting stuck. Not always, but often enough to be a serious problem.
The file starts playing but a bit in (all from a few seconds to almost at the end of the 1 hr show) it just stops and the only way to keep playing it is to reload the file. To me it seems like a buffering problem.

I don't understand why.
If anyone has ever had a similar problem, please tell me what I am missing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "stuck"? Do you mean the audio appears to play normally, but then stops at some point and won't continue?

Comment: exactly. the file starts playing but a bit in (all from a few seconds to almost at the end of the 1 hr show) it just stops and the only way to keep playing it is to reload the file. To me it seems like a buffering problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself to this one.
After double-, triple-, quadruple-checking everything it hit me, the site was hosted by GoDaddy and I know that it is not the best quality you can expect from them. (Actually they are really bad in more than one way. Never go with GoDaddy if you can avoid it. Just my personal opinion.)
We changed the hosting and the problem was gone.
To bad it had cost me days of work for nothing.